# hg command to list subrepositories

Tags: mercurial

Is there a command that can be constructed to list all the subrepositories of a Mercurial repository? Something like what the `git submodule` command does? (I am attempting to process them programmatically.)

As far as I can tell, the best option currently is to write a parser that processes .hgsub (dealing with the various optional sections like `[subpaths]`) and that seems much less optimal than relying on `hg` to parse the file. But I can't find a command that does it.

Is there one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onsub` extension. The repository linked in the [Mercurial wiki](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/OnsubExtension) disappeared, but I found https://bitbucket.org/kvaster/onsub which looks maintained.

I created a mini repo with two subrepos as follows:

```
$ find . -type d -name '.hg'
.hg              <== outer repo
nested/.hg       <== subrepo
nested2/.hg      <== subrepo
```

The corresponding `.hgsub` is very simple:

```
nested = nested
nested2 = nested2
```

Example 1:

```
$ hg --config extensions.onsub=~/src/onsub/onsub.py onsub --verbose "hg status"
executing 'hg status' in nested
executing 'hg status' in nested2
```

Example 2:

```
$ hg --config extensions.onsub=~/src/onsub/onsub.py onsub "hg root"
/Users/hello/tmp/foo/nested
/Users/hello/tmp/foo/nested2
```

Example 3: using environment variables provided by `onsub`:

```
$ hg --config extensions.onsub=~/src/onsub/onsub.py onsub "echo; set | grep HG_"

HG_REPO=/Users/hello/tmp/foo
HG_SUBPATH=nested
HG_SUBURL=nested

HG_REPO=/Users/hello/tmp/foo
HG_SUBPATH=nested2
HG_SUBURL=nested2
```

As usual, you can get help with:

```
hg --config extensions.onsub=~/src/onsub/onsub.py help onsub
```

The `--config ...` on the command-line shows how to enable an extension without editing your `$HOME/.hgrc`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing .hgsub I'd parse .hgsubstate instead - it is guaranteed to have one line per subrepository instead:

```
for i in $(cat .hgsubstate | cut -d\  -f2); do echo $i; done
```